# ID alfanumérico autoincremental en php para registrar en MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Haber si me explico bien. Estoy haciendo un proyecto de clase en el cual quiero hacer que cada usuario tenga un ID único autoincremental alfanumerico hecho en código. Por ejemplo:

ES0000001

Y que eso vaya incrementandose cada vez que un usuario se registra, ¿Esto es posible?
He intentado hacer $numero = 0000001; y $letra = ES; y luego juntarlo en $ID = $letra + $numero;

Pero me sale el error de Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in D:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoDaw\register.php

Codigo

```
<?php session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        header('location: index.php');
    }



    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
        $letra = "ES";
        $numero = 000001;
        $id = ($letra + $numero);
        $password = hash('sha512', $password);
        $password2 = hash('sha512', $password2);

        $error = '';

        if (empty($email) or empty($usuario) or empty($password) or empty($password2)){

            $error .= '<i>Favor de rellenar todos los campos</i>';
        }else{
            try{
                $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=service_ticketing', 'root', '');
            }catch(PDOException $prueba_error){
                echo "Error: " . $prueba_error->getMessage();
            }

            $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuarios = :usuario LIMIT 1');
            $statement->execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario));
            $resultado = $statement->fetch();


            if ($resultado != false){
                $error .= '<i>Este usuario ya existe</i>';
            }

            if ($password != $password2){
                $error .= '<i> Las contraseñas no coinciden</i>';
            }


        }

        if ($error == ''){
            $numero++;
            $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO login (id, email, usuario, password) VALUES (:id, :email, :usuario, :password)');
            $statement->execute(array(
                'id'=>$id,
                ':email' => $email,
                ':usuario' => $usuario,
                ':password' => $password

            ));

            $error .= '<i style="color: green;">Usuario registrado exitosamente</i>';
        }
    }


    require 'frontend/register-vista.php';

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar un procedimiento almacenado, para el código autoincrementado, seria el siguiente:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertarLogin (
in Email varchar(30),
in Usuario varchar(50),
in Password varchar(50))
BEGIN
Declare Codigo varchar(30);
set Codigo = (SELECT CONCAT('ES00000',COUNT(e.Codigo) + 1) FROM Login e ORDER BY 1 desc limit 0,1);
 if (Codigo is null) then set Codigo = 'ES000001'; end if;
 INSERT INTO login values (Codigo,Email,Usuario,Password);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Para llamar al procedimiento desde php:

```
call InsertarLogin('$email','$usuario,'$password')
```

Answer (score 1):

En PHP el operador para concatenar strings es '.', no '+'
Al poner más estás intentando sumar un nro. a un string, y por eso obtienes el error.

Comment: Ahora hace el registro, pero no me añade el ID

Comment: Pero qué ocurre, te dá un error, o qué? Explica un poco más lo que pasa.

Comment: No me da error, simplemente cuando hago el registro en el ID pone 0, y cuando quiero insertar otro, lo hace correctamente, pero no aparece, supongo que es por que no pueden tener el mismo ID y por eso no aparece

Comment: Ah, pero lo que tu quieres es que para cada petición desde el navegador, te incremente el id? Pues eso no se puede hacer con PHP, porque cada petición es una nueva sesión para PHP, las variables no se guardan entre peticiones.
Además aún si lo hicieran, cada vez que recibes una petición estás asignando el valor 1 a $numero, por lo tanto siempre va a ser 1 (luego lo incrementas, pero lo que insertas en la tabla es $id, no $numero).
Podrías guardar $numero en la session, pero realmente no es aconsejable,
Lo correcto es que definas el campo id como AUTO_INCREMENT en mySQL